# Viewing Magento model data changes on before/after save event?

Tags: php, magento

It should be simple:

- Hook a `MODEL_save_after` event (or `MODEL_save_before` if that’s more appropriate).
- Check `getData()` vs g`etOrigData()` to see what changes the user has made.

In the **customer_address** model, edited through the backend, both save events are triggered twice. The first time `customer_address_save_before` is triggered, followed by `customer_address_save_after`.

In both cases `getOrigData()` and `getData()` are identical, except `getData()` has a new **updated_at** value, and has a **store_id** set (is this a bug?). So, the model doesn’t have the submitted data from the user yet. The events are both before entering user data or validation, so this is of no use.

`customer_address_save_before` is triggered, followed by `customer_address_save_after` a second time. This time (in both cases), `getOrigData()` is empty, and `getData()` now has all the submitted data from the user. So I can’t compare these events either! It appears this is after validation, saving, the lot!

Why the save process appears to occur twice? Magento v1.3.2.4.

Comment: What's the name of the event you're hooking into?

Comment: customer_address_save_after or customer_address_save_before.

Interestingly, the data in the model in the two cases is identical!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wound up hooking customer_address_save_before, and comparing the results to what was in the database like so:

```
<?php
customer_address_save_before_listener ($event)
{
  $address = $event->getCustomerAddress();

  $database_address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($address->getId());
}
?>
```

And comparing the getData() returns from the two. There were three gotcha's that I came across:

- Use getEntityTypeId() on $address and check it. Despite hooking 'customer_address_save_before', you also get OrderAddress models being sent to your listener (this seems wrong to me, but ah well).
- Check for arrays in $address->getData() values. For example, 'street' is returned from the DB as a single string, while the address your listener is passed has this exploded on endlines.
- The CustomerAddress your listener is passed has a 'store_id'. Even though CustomerAddress doesn't store 'store_id', and it doesn't get saved (or loaded from) the database.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the gotchas - the OrderAddress is a nasty gotcha! For those looking for how to validate the EntityTypeId, this snippet should return the correct value: `$iAddressTypeId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('customer_address')->getEntityTypeId();`

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! - Normally you can't edit an order address in the admin, so I'm assuming that this was being fired upon order creation? What Magento versions were you seeing that happening in? - I'm now using this (https://gist.github.com/theloveofcode/75f0ad9b9fafde523bee) to detect changes, letting me notify admins of which field in particular changed.